# Strange behavior of Chrome on simplest hover

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm currently wrapping my head around a strange problem occurring only in chrome. I have tried to breakdown the code to the most basic part of it, in fact its only some lines of simple css&html.

Here is the code:

```
<style>
    li > ul {display: none}    
    li:hover {background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);}    
    li:hover > ul { display: block;}
</style>
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>1</div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div>2</div>
                <ul>
                    <li>2a</li>
                    <li>2b</li>
                    <li>2c</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>4</div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div>5</div>
                <ul>
                    <li>5a</li>
                    <li>5b</li>
                    <li>5c</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>6</li>
            <li>7</li>
            <li>8</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>9</div>
        <ul>
            <li>10</li>
            <li>11</li>
            <li>12</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

looks simple, huh? if i put that in a .html file and load that file for the first time in chrome i'm unable to move my mouseover the li with the number 2. because it keeps disappearing before i reach it. li no. 5 and even 5a can be reached without any problems.
after either opening devtools or resizing the window it works as expected, could someone please explain this behavior or even come up with a solution for that - in my opinion - really weird behavior. 
In firefox & ie it works without any problem, tried to make a fiddle but i could not reconstruct the problem in the fiddle.

Comment: unable to reproduce in fiddle, the misbehavior only appears if it is not in the fiddle frame, but in a .html file.

Comment: I can hover the li with the number 2 withut any problems

Comment: yeah thx for that ;) but i was not unable to create a fiddle, but the problem just does not seem to occur in the fiddle.. do you understand what i mean?

Comment: Then it's a problem from your end...

Comment: in the fiddle i can hover without any problem too! but if i put the code into a let's say hover.html file and open that file under certain circumstances (in chrome, wihtout dev-tools open, before any manipulation to the window) i can not hover li no.2

Comment: i tested it in chrome version::  41.0.2272.89 m (64-bit) and 43.0.2337.2 canary (64-bit) btw

Comment: Has the style tag been put inside the body?

Comment: thank you for the down-votes of the question .... but i will make a video of this behavior and post it to prove the problem, tried it on different machines too so i do not believe that its an error on my side!

Comment: style tag is in the header @Knu

Comment: tried different OS chrome 41 on mac does not show that problem - but win 8 does!

Comment: Unfairly downvoted question.

Comment: that's what i was talking about!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You are not crazy and your question in my opinion has been unfairly downvoted.

it has happened to me on one of my webs that has always worked nicely. and I could just replicate the error on a surface pro under windows 8.1 (chrome).

The mistake happens after you open a new sesion and if you want to get rid of it, just open a new tag, minimize and maximize your window or just inspect the web (Ctrol+Shift+I)

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Week%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=468669

Comment: oh my god :) thank you very much i was really thinking i'm getting crazy! thx & have a nice day!